# android espresso:test for new activity launch on button click is failing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I am testing whether a button click migrates to new activity using intended,and it is displaying the new activity being launched on device,but test case is failing,I am using the following code for same.

```
onView(withId(R.id.bt_click)).perform(click());
intended(hasComponent(hasClassName(CodeVerify.class.getName())));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to make it like this

```
    Intents.init();
    onView(withId(R.id.bt_click)).perform(click());
    intended(hasComponent(CodeVerify.class.getName()));
    Intents.release();
```

if you provide more details it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `IntentsTestRule` instead of a `ActivityTestRule` which will automatically call init() and release() before/after the test.